# Какой стандарт оформления списка литературы использовать для "computer science" статей?

Tags: ссылки, стандарт, статьи, оформление

Есть достаточно много различных стилей/стандартов оформления списка литературы для публикации статьи.

Вот примеры: `APA style, MLA style, The Chicago Manual of Style, Bluebook, ALWD Citation Manual, ASA style, Harvard referencing and Vancouver system, IEEE`

Но какой из стилей/стандартов принято использовать для публикаций  статей в сфере `IT` (`Computer Science`). В частности, я хотел бы опубликовать статью по теме машинного обучения (**на английском языке**). На данный момент, пока не определился, где именно буду публиковать, но на данном этапе хотел бы, чтобы оформление было представлено в формате, с которым, в принципе, знакомо большинство журналов, посвященных IT тематике. Какой стандарт оформления списка литературы принято использовать для статей в сфере IT?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, разные журналы могут использовать разный формат оформления списка литературы. Если вы будете набирать статьи, например, в LaTeX, то сможете применять к ним различные стили оформления, в том числе списков литературы.

Answer (score 1):

В общем разбираться с `LaTeX` времени нет. Использовал бесплатный сервис по генерации списка литературы. Необходимо выбрать объект, на который ссылаетесь (журнал, книга, сайт, статья) и указать все необходимые данные (название, название журнала, авторов, год выпуска, издательство и т.д.) и сайт сгенерирует для вас литературную ссылку в выбранном Вами стандарте\стиле (поддерживается множество стандартов оформления списка литературы, в том числе и популярные: `AMA, ASA, APA, MLA, Harvard, Chicago, APSA, Bluebook, OSCOLA, IEEE`). Все ваши ссылки хранятся у Вас и никуда не деваются. В любой момент, если нужно сменить стандарт, вы одним кликом меняете стандарт и Ваша ссылка меняется на нужный формат без дополнительных корректировок. Оптимальный вариант. Выбрал для себя стандарт `IEEE`, указал необходимые данные и в один клик была сгенерирована ссылка.

Вот сайт:

> [RefME | Free Referencing Generator](https://www.refme.com/)

Еще есть такой:

> [Cite This For Me: Reference Generator](https://www.citethisforme.com/)

но он платный.

`LaTeX` для меня сложноват для такой элементарной вещи как литературная ссылка.

Comment: У RefME сменился владелец. Поэтому возможно что сервис больше не является бесплатным.